# How do I get rid of a script that tries to run at the end of sudo apt-get update?

Tags: command-line, apt

I wrote a bash script and placed it in my `/usr/bin` directory. Since then, I've deleted the file as it didn't work as intended. But now, every time I run `sudo apt-get update`, it also tries to run that script I wrote. How do I stop it from trying the script every time I call `sudo apt-get update`.

[image: sncreenshot of terminal]

Comment: "I was following some internet tutorials" is useless if you do not add a link ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds to me like you **overwrote** the core utility `/usr/bin/test` with a script of your own called `test`.

Rather than simply deleting the apt script that is trying to execute `/usr/bin/test`, you should fix it properly by re-installing the coreutils package:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall coreutils
```

In future, **don't** place random files of your own in `/usr/bin` - the place for that kind of thing is either `~/bin` or (system wide) `/usr/local/bin`. In any case, it's wise not to call them `test` since that's the name of an important existing utility.

Answer (score -2):

Go under Settings -> Software & Updates then go to the **Other Sources** tab and look to make sure there isn't a link to your failed bash script. If it's there highlight ->enter your password -> and click <kbd>Remove</kbd>. Once that is done the system will ask you to refresh your cache let it do it, open terminal and then run another

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Let us know what you find out.